# Nose como hacer para que el resultados, no salga entre corchetes

Tags: javascript, string, bucle-for, condiciones, filtro

```
function stringMasLarga(strings) {

// La función llamada 'stringMasLarga', recibe como argumento un arreglo de strings llamado 'strings'

  // y debe devolver el string más largo que hay en el arreglo (Es decir el de mayor cantidad de caracteres)

  // Ej:
  // stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']); debe retornar 'guten tag'

  // stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']); debe retornar 'JavaScript'

   

    let stringgrande = [];
  

    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    if (strings [i] > stringgrande)
    stringgrande = strings[i];
    }
     return stringgrande;
   }
```

Comment: No pongas la descripcion del codigo asi, simplemente pon el codigo completo de esa funcion y como la usas, tu codigo esta truncado a mi parecer. Es bueno que pongas una descripcion, pero no de esa manera.

Answer (score 1):

Probá así:

function stringMasLarga(strings) {
return strings.reduce((max,actual)=> actual.length > max.length ? actual: max);
}

El reduce recorre el array de strings que le estás mandando, y "reduce" el contenido del array según la función que le pases, persistiendo el valor en el primer parámetro de esa función.

Por ende: la función adentro del reduce devuelve el actual que se está recorriendo, siempre y cuando la cantidad de carateres sea mayor que max. Si la cantidad de carateres de actual es menor o igual que max, devuelve max. Ese valor devuelto es el que se persiste en el parámetro del arrow function "max".

Al final del recorrido del array, el reduce devuelve lo que persistió en "max".

Es más simple que hacerlo con un for.

El snippet:

```js
function stringMasLarga(strings) {
  return strings.reduce((max,actual)=> actual.length > max.length ? actual: max);
}

 var result = stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']);
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result + "<br/>";

 var result2 = stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']);
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result2 + "<br/>";
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Ejemplo en jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vdjwm6s4/

Comment: Es buena respuesta, pero la puedes mejorar usando un fragmento de código (code snippet) para que el ejemplo se pueda probar aquí mismo y, de preferencia, usando los datos que sugiere AP.

Comment: Siii era asi! Gracias!

Comment: Te falta explicación, estas aportando una respuesta que quizá funcione pero al usuario no le quedara tan claro como a ti lo que se supone que esta haciendo ese codigo, es como si le pusieras a crear un juego en `java` sin explicarle antes lo que deberias usar y porque se usa.

Comment: Tenés razón, ahora le explico.

Answer (score 0):

sort ordena de menor a mayor y .pop saca el ultimo valor restante, o sea el mayor de todos

```js
function stringMasLarga(strings) { 
  return strings.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).pop();
}

console.log(
stringMasLarga(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag']));

console.log(
stringMasLarga(['JavaScript', 'HTML', 'CSS']));
```